# Using sequelize cli with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use sequelize with typescript, but don't know how.
I installed a package named sequelize-cli-typescript, but it does not work with sequelize v6.
And I know it is better to use migrations to perform my database. How can I do that?

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html?

Comment: Wanna use migrations, not sync

Comment: This question leaves us to ask so many other questions we don't know where to start to help.

Comment: OK I just want to create my migrations with sequelize-cli, and output a ts file instead of js file. That's it, I don't wanna add models manually and then sync them. I just want to add models using migrations. sequelize-cli package is for js, not for ts. It generates js file,not ts.

Answer (score 7):

You pretty much need to transpile your code into javascript if you're going to use migrations, because sequelize-cli doesn't know anything about typescript.  We compile our stuff to `./dist` right before running `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` via `npx tsc -p .` with a `tsconfig.json` file that has these lines:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    // ...
    "outDir": "dist",
    // ...
  }
}
```

The `.sequelizerc` file (which is used by sequelize-cli only) will also point to dist, e.g.:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   'config': path.resolve('./dist/src/config', 'config.js'),
   'models-path': path.resolve('./dist/src/db', 'models'),
   'seeders-path': path.resolve('./dist/src/db', 'seeders'),
   'migrations-path': path.resolve('./dist/src/db', 'migrations')
}
```

Comment: gives me this Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-module-resolver' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74231128/error-running-sequelize-seeder-on-typescript-based-setup

Answer (score 5):

Use [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug). It powers sequelize cli.