# How to configure sequelize, and sequelize-cli to work with typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, config, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

How to Configure Sequelize and Sequelize-CLI to work with TypeScript

I have a project to maintain using sequelize and typescript and I tried as hard as possible to configure them, but I couldn't. I cannot generate models using the cli, and sometimes when I find some configurations online the cli generates a js file, or sometimes generates a ts file but cannot migrate.

***Note:*** when I work using sequelize and javascript everything works fine, but for this I have to work with typescript.

I need an explanation for how to configure sequelize and typescript from scratch, or the configuration code if possible.

I even used sequelize-typescript, sequelize-cli-typescript dependencies and I couldn't configure the application to create a model or migrate the database using sequelize.

Comment: Do you just want to generate migrations for your typescript project or do you want to execute typescript code inside the migrations?

Comment: @Ralle I want to generate migrations using cli

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in reading this as well: [Sequelize CLI & DB migrations with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371646/sequelize-cli-db-migrations-with-typescript)

...

**Note:** Just found out that now you can use `sequelize-cli-ts-js` npm package to automate this process instead. the package will automatically create typescript files for you and will work seamlessly for both javascript and typescript.

...

I was also facing a similar issue and resolved it.

the issue that I faced was that I was not able to run any CLI after changing the config file extension from `.js` to `.ts`.

```
ERROR: Error reading "config/database.ts". Error: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for
```

As you wanted to run it on a typescript-based project. and Sequelize-cli seems to have no support for typescript by default and causes an error message of not being able to understand files with `.ts` extensions.

I will consider you have also configured the typescript in your project.

to be able to load configs from a typescript file we need to use a javascript file. to do this, create a file named `sequelize.config.js` in your project's root directory with the following content:

```
require('ts-node/register');
const config = require('./config/database.ts'); // Change the path to your config file

// for debug purposes
console.log({config})

module.exports = config;
```

This file uses ts-node/register to enable TypeScript support for Sequelize CLI.

now in `.sequelizerc` file correct the path for the config, for me it looks like this.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve('sequelize.config.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('db', 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('db', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('db', 'migrations'),
};
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: you can also use `sequelize-cli-ts-js` package that works seamlessly for both typescript and javascript projects.

Answer (score -3):

There is no need to use sequelize-cli with TypeScript. Just go with JavaScript and your good. For utilizing TypeScript using Sequelize I'd recommend reading the docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/